# Problema al querer leer JSON hecho PHP desde Java

Tags: php, java, json, gson

estoy intentando obtener un JSON desde PHP, que me devuelve el resultado de una consulta (SELECT) de una base de datos.

Estoy usando GSON, para convertir el JSON obtenido a un objeto en Java.

Mi problema esta en que no me deja crear los objeto y me devuelve un Excepción.
Nose si lo que me devuelve PHP me devuelve en un formato correcto para poder ser interpretado en GSON.

Lo que si al momento de ver el JSON en consola para ver lo que me devuelve, me pone una especie de punto al inicio y otro al final, cosa que si se los saco anda perfectamente, pero me gustaría saber cual puede ser el error y que puedo estar haciendo mal.

MI PHP es el siguiente:

```
<?php
$servidor="localhost";
$nombre_bd="test2";
$username="root";
$password="";
$conexion = mysql_connect($servidor, $username, $password) or die ("No se ha podido conectar al servidor de Base de datos");
  
mysql_select_db($nombre_bd, $conexion) or die ("xD");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuario";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $conexion);
$array = array();
$i = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $array[$i] = $row;
  $i ++;
}
$json = json_encode($array, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
echo $json;
?>﻿
```

El Java de donde hago la petición:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package prueba.comsumir.webservice;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

/**
 *
 * @author Pablo
 */
public class PruebaComsumirWebservice {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Usuario usuario = new Usuario(1, "User1", "123");
        System.out.println(usuario.toString());
        URL url;
        try {
            // Creando un objeto URL
            url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/Sitio%201/code.php");

            // Realizando la petición GET
            URLConnection con = url.openConnection();

            // Leyendo el resultado
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    con.getInputStream()));

            String linea;
            String json = "";
            while ((linea = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(linea);
                json += linea;
            }
            //{"id":1,"usuario":"usuario1","contrasenia":"asd"}
            Usuario usuario1 = new Gson().fromJson(json, Usuario.class);
            System.out.println(usuario.getUsuario());
            
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Y la clase Usuario:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package prueba.comsumir.webservice;

/**
 *
 * @author Pablo
 */
public class Usuario {
    private int id;
    private String usuario;
    private String contrasenia;

    public Usuario(int id, String usuario, String contrasenia) {
        this.id = id;
        this.usuario = usuario;
        this.contrasenia = contrasenia;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }

    public void setUsuario(String usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }

    public String getContrasenia() {
        return contrasenia;
    }

    public void setContrasenia(String contrasenia) {
        this.contrasenia = contrasenia;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("id:%s, usuario:%s, contrasenia:%s", id, usuario, contrasenia);
    }
}
```

Cuando ejecuto el código desde Netbeans, me devuelve el siguiente JSON: y me da la siguiente Excepción:

```
{"0":{"0":"1","id":"1","1":"user1","usuario":"user1","2":"asd","contrasenia":"asd"},"1":{"0":"2","id":"2","1":"user2","usuario":"user2","2":"dsa","contrasenia":"dsa"}}﻿
Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 169 path $
    at com.google.gson.Gson.assertFullConsumption(Gson.java:855)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:845)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:793)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:765)
    at prueba.comsumir.webservice.PruebaComsumirWebservice.main(PruebaComsumirWebservice.java:48)
Caused by: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 169 path $
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.syntaxError(JsonReader.java:1567)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.checkLenient(JsonReader.java:1416)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.doPeek(JsonReader.java:546)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.peek(JsonReader.java:429)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.assertFullConsumption(Gson.java:851)
    ... 4 more
C:\Users\Pablo\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

Un saludo y gracias desde ya.

Comment: En principio el json que llega no responde a la clase java que usas con Gson. Lo que llega es un array, y adentro los Usuarios tienen 6 atributos, los 3 que pusiste en la clase Usuario y los mismos atributos con indices 0,1, y 2

Comment: Gracias, ¿Y  como lo puedo hacer para que el php, me devuelva un JSON compatible para que lo pueda interpretar con GSON?

Comment: que esperás recibir, un Usuario o una Lista de usuarios?

Comment: En si seria una lista de usuarios, igual dependería de la consulta SQL y los registros que me devuelva, como pueden ser 1 0 1000. Seria una lista de usuarios, pero no entiendo como hacer que me devuelva una JSON con la lista de usuarios compatible con GSON.

Answer (score 0):

En el código original estas devolviendo los registros como array (no como array asociativo) por eso llegan con un índice numérico. Y no se porque además se agregan los atributos, tal vez sea el `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` en el `json_encode`.

Por otro lado en el ejemplo uso mysqli en lugar de mysql que está hace tiempo deprecado.

```
$con=mysqli_connect($servidor,$username,$password,$nombre_bd);

if(!$con) die('error conectando');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuario";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

$rtn = array();

if($result){
    $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    while($row !== null){
      $rtn[] = $row;
      $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
return json_encode($rtn);
```

Del lado java, vas a necesitar dos clases:

`Usuario`, que ya la tenés y `Usuarios` que tiene la lista.

```
public class Usuarios{
    private List<Usuario> usuarios;
    // getter & setter
}
```

Y la deserialización:

```
//{"id":1, "usuario":"usuario1", "contrasenia":"asd"}
Usuarios usuarios = new Gson().fromJson(json, Usuarios.class);
```